# How to redirect specific calls to other IP?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a domain, and some static content. I would like all of the static content to be served from my domain. However, I would like all requests with **/api/** - for example: http://mydomain/api/users) to be forwarded to my other server, with IP address of for example 10.1.10.100 (irrelevant at this time).

How can I do it?

Comment: You can do with with a rewriterule with the [P] flag to proxy the request to the back end server in an htaccess file, or, preferably (and more easily), with ProxyPass in you virtual host.

Comment: The technical term is that you *"reverse proxy"* those requests.

Answer (score 3):

You can use mod_proxy, in httpd.conf :

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /api/ http://10.1.10.100/api/
ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://10.1.10.100/api/
```

Or, as for Unbeliever's comment, in .htaccess you can use a combination of RewriteRule and ProxyPassReverse, there is an answer to this same question using the second alternative:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808506/can-proxypass-and-proxypassreverse-work-in-htaccess

Comment: Please note, this configuration would need to be in the main Apache configuration and will not work in htaccess files, as the original post suggested the requirement was by its tags.

Comment: Thanks @Unbeliever, I'll update my reply. Seems you can use mod_rewrite with the [P] flag in .htaccess though